# Create custom bootable linux image; not a livecd

Tags: linux, kernel, bios, grub, grub2

So I've compiled my kernel and initrd. How can I then create an image and install grub to actually load this image from a disk? My goal isn't to create a livecd out of it that is bootable from USB, as there are plenty of articles on that. My goal is to create an image (I know `dd if=/dev/zero of=linux.img ...` is what I need to create an overall image) and simply write that image to the first sector of the disk using dd and have it just boot from there. However, where does my kernel and initrd go in that img? Right behind each other? This disk isn't going to have any partitions. It's a custom kernel and minimal busybox setup that is stripped down. I therefore do not need a /boot partition and all the "files" aren't going to live on another partition because there isn't going to be one or much of any files.

I know the MBR is 512 bytes and I assume `grub` is also just going to overwrite 512 bytes to the first sector. But how do I even get grub installed on the image? Would `grub-install linux.img` even work? I know that `grub` knows where to load the kernel and initrd from a normal setup because those live in /boot but this "image" doesn't have partitions on it to look in `/boot` . Do I just set root to itself?

Any help would be appreciated

Initrd creation procedure: https://pastebin.com/ti9LXakx

Current init script within initrd:

```
#!/bin/sh   
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys 
mount -t proc proc /proc 
mount -t devtmpfs udev /dev 
exec /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

512 bytes is far too little for GRUB: on a classic BIOS-booting MBR-partitioned disk, GRUB also places parts of itself in the normally-unused blocks #1..#2047, as modern OSs place the start of the first partition exactly 1 MiB from the beginning of the disk, at block #2048. Typically it might use about 100 of those blocks, depending on which features are selected to be built into the GRUB core image and which are left to be loaded as GRUB modules (from *some* filesystem).

And you don't even get all of the 512 bytes in the MBR block (block #0): at minimum, two bytes at the end of the MBR block are occupied by the signature that tells the BIOS that this disk is bootable.

GRUB has a built-in expectation that the disk/partition/logical volume/encrypted volume it finds its configuration file, kernel and initrd on *contains a filesystem of some sort*. If you want to read the kernel and initramfs by just reading consecutive blocks off the disk, that sounds more like what the ancient LILO bootloader did... I wonder if it's still usable with the modern kernels?

In short, leaving out the partition table is not the advantage you think it is. With a custom configuration, you *could* make GRUB read blocks #A .. #B as the kernel, and #(B+1).. #C as the initramfs file, but that would be just making your own life more difficult for no good reason.

And since you mentioned a Live CD, if you want your image to also work when burned to a CD-ROM/DVD or used as a virtual CD in a virtual machine, you must create a hybrid image that works both as a HDD image with a bootloader in MBR, and as a valid ISO9660 CD/DVD image with El Torito boot extensions - which requires a separate bootloader in a different location on the image.

And if you want UEFI compatibility... "You must unlearn what you have learned."

With UEFI, the *system firmware* will expect to find a FAT filesystem (preferably FAT32, but other forms of FAT will also be acceptable for newer versions of UEFI), and the bootloader as a file with a particular name in that filesystem. Since the filesystem is already there to satisfy the firmware requirements for UEFI bootability, you might as well use it to have the kernel, initramfs and the configuration of your bootloader in there as regular files.

To create your image, you could use `losetup` to bind it to a `/dev/loop<device_number>` device, after which you can use the device just like a real disk. If the image contains a partition table, you can use `losetup -P` to automatically create partition devices of the form `/dev/loop<device_number>p<partition_number>` to allow easy access to any partitions within the image file.

Comment: I find `kpartx` simpler to manage the loop device with partitioned media.

Comment: i was able to figure this all out by reading about loop devices so i ended up setting that up, mounting it, then grub-installing onto the mounted boot. but you are correct about using `losetup` because that is exactly how it is done. the only question i have is, if my kernel is 1.9M and my initrd is only 5M, why then do I need 16M to create my image file from /dev/zero? I tried with less and there isn't enough space. Does LILO take up that much space as well? I had assumed I would end up with just whatever my kernel and initrd is, not so much extra.

Comment: Some filesystem types have minimum size requirements (for example, you cannot make a FAT32 partition smaller than 32M), and the filesystem metadata (i.e. directories, inodes and some way to keep track which blocks are allocated and which are not) take some space too. But in modern terms, 16M is *tiny*: unless you work with embedded systems or retrocomputing, I would see no need to try fit things tighter than that.

Comment: yes I am considering working with embedded systems. Are they using other tools to get this done? I've stripped down my busybox as much as possible as well but disappointed that its still just about 9-10M but I am forced to make my image 16M because of the loop device.

Comment: The limit is not caused by the loop device. Are you partitioning the image? Modern partitioning tools will normally place the start of the 1st partition at exactly 1 MiB from the start of the device for data alignment reasons. Which filesystem type are you using, and what parameters are you using for the `mkfs` tool? If using a journaling filesystem like `ext4`, it will allocate space for the filesystem journal... but if the media is read-only during expected use, you won't need a journaling filesystem.

Comment: while this does boot directly from the disk after using dd, it isn't what i expected. it doesn't mount the actual disk. i could mount that with `mount -a` if i have the right options in `/etc/fstab` but manually throws an error. this partition `/dev/sda1` ends up just showing my /boot directory and the kernel and initrd images if i mount it somewhere. do i basically have a livecd thats not persistent that I wrote to the beginning of a hard disk? it is mounting `rootfs` onto `/`. i might as well create a livecd out of this? https://mvallim.github.io/live-custom-ubuntu-from-scratch/

Comment: You said you only need the kernel and initrd/initramfs, and it seems to me you got just that, similar to how the previously-free disk erase tool DBAN and [its successor ShredOS](https://github.com/PartialVolume/shredos.x86_64) work. If you want to mount the disk too, you could write an initramfs script to do it. But since you don't give full details of what you're doing or what your custom image is supposed to do, it's hard to give you exact recommendations.

Comment: the image should just be the OS itself on the disk, without having to "install" anything. I guess much like how an embedded system would operate. Here is the script I used to create the image https://pastebin.com/ti9LXakx i then dd'd it to the disk

Comment: Your initrd gets full control of the system; it probably should include a script that mounts `/proc`, reads the `root=` parameter from `/proc/cmdline`, and then mounts the suggested device (after first creating the device node, if necessary). Since a minimal userland could fit inside the initrd, it can be a perfectly legitimate choice to not mount anything else. That said, you are using an `ext4` filesystem; by using `ext2` instead, you might get back a few MB that are currently getting allocated to the ext4 filesystem journal.

Comment: yes my init looks like this: `#!/bin/sh
 
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t devtmpfs udev /dev
exec /bin/sh`

Comment: yes i know i can just execute the binary i want instead of /bin/sh. ive tested this before and ensure keeping it in a while loop so the kernel doesn't exit and panic. but how come then, nothing is actually saved to the disk if i write to a file? it seems like the only place it would actually save anything is in `/dev/sda1` which itself is not mounted until i intentionally do so from `mount -a` since doing it on the cmd does not work, throws some kind of error. i am interested in making this into a livecd now actually but avoiding all the ubuntu stuff since this isn't debian-specific

Comment: Unless you mount something else, you will be working with initrd/initramfs, which is essentially a RAM disk. It has got the extracted contents of your initrd file, but is totally non-persistent. What is the "some kind of error" you are getting from your mount attempt?

Comment: `EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: disabled.`

Comment: That is a routine message when mounting an ext4 filesystem, not an error.

Comment: but if i do `mount -a`, i can `mount /dev/sda1` because i put this entry into `fstab`. this is the `fstab` in my initrd. not in `/dev/sda1` which only contains `/boot`: `/dev/sda1 /mnt ext4 noauto,users,exec 0 0`

Comment: it won't mount manually, only when i do `mount -a`

Comment: Your mount options include `noauto`, so `mount -a` should **not** mount that entry. The `EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode...` message means the mount was actually **successful**.

Comment: ok. i guess i would like to know why does my system not behave like a regular installed system on a disk? on a regular disk, /boot contains the kernel and initrd which mine does. but why do i have `none on / type rootfs (rw)` when i typed `mount` ? i expected 1 entire partition `/dev/sda1` which i defined in the build-image.sh i linked showing my grub configuration. i had expected my /dev/sda1 to mount on `/`, not on `/mnt`. of course i can't put `/` because rootfs has taken domain over that. so what do i actually have? an initrd? fake live system? why won't my /dev/sda1 load on `/` ?

Comment: On a regular OS installation, initramfs/initrd mounts the real root filesystem to a temporary mount point, then unmounts all other filesystems and does a **pivot_root operation** to switch to the new root filesystem. Your initrd is not doing that. See `man 8 pivot_root`.